# Prove that integration of a differential $k$-form is independent of choice of basis

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds, differential-topology

This is Exercise 4 of Section 33 of Munkres' "Analysis on Manifolds" book:

(Let $A$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^k$.) If $\eta$ is a $k$-form in $\mathbb{R}^k$ and if $\mathbf{a}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{a}_k$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^k$, then what is the (non-trivial linear) relationship between the integrals $$\int_A \eta $$ and $$\int_{\mathbf{x} \in A} \eta(\mathbf{x})\left((\mathbf{x};\mathbf{a}_1),\ldots,(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{a}_k)\right) \mathrm{?}$$
Furthermore, show that if the matrix $M$ formed by the vectors $\mathbf{a}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{a}_k$ in order as column vectors (i.e. $M$ is the matrix representation of $\mathbb{R}^k$ in the basis vectors $\mathbf{a}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{a}_k$) is special orthogonal, then the integrals above are equal.

I figured that the solution might have had something to do with change of basis matrices or with some manipulation of elementary 1-forms or something, but I'm really not sure.

Comment: I've found that redefining elementary 1-forms in terms of the basis vectors given in the problem might be a step in the right direction; I think I can prove this if the basis is special orthogonal, but I don't know what happens if it isn't.

Comment: Apologies if double-commenting isn't allowed (I wanted to leave comments separate so as to show my process and how long it took), but I have reason to believe that the second integral is the first times $\mathrm{det}(M)$. I think this follows from redefining the elementary $k$-forms in terms of the basis given in the problem, but I'm not 100% sure. If $M$ is special orthogonal, then $\mathrm{det}(M) = 1$, hence the integrals are equal.